# Anyone used EmpireDB?

Tags: apache, orm, jpa

Has anyone used the [EmpireDB](http://incubator.apache.org/empire-db/index.html) from Apache? I am planning to use it and would like to know if there are any known issues with this new concept?

I have used ORM like Hibernate and JPA. But EmpireDB sounds like it easy.

Anyone knows its limitations then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EmpireDB places impositions on your model classes; you can't just persist your designed model. You add a dependence to their codebase (which could change later). You have to write a lot more code to use it (using its Tutorial) than you would using JDO or JPA. How that is somehow "easy" i can't think.

Answer (score 0):

If you need full control over the sql, you don't want to use entities for everything and hate sql/jpql strings it is the perfect tool.

It depends largely on what you plan to do with it.